# How to prove this equation??

Tags: summation

How to prove this equation :

$$\sum _{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)\:=\sum _{k=n}^{2n}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Pick a small $n$. Write out the first four terms of the series. You should find there is some telescoping involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by induction.  Check $n=1$ first.  Then assume it is true for $j$.  $$\sum _{k=1}^{j+1}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{j}\left(\frac{1}{2k-1}-\frac{1}{2k}\right)+\frac 1{2j+1}-\frac 1{2j+2}\\
=\sum _{k=j}^{2j}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{1}{j}+\frac 1{2j+1}-\frac 1{2j+2}\\=\sum _{k=j+1}^{2j+2}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac 1{j+1}$$ and we see it is true for $j+1$